# Application of the GDPR to emails one has sent

Tags: gdpr

Reading https://gdpr-info.eu/issues/personal-data/, it seems you could use the GDPR for, well, unexpected request. For example, if I ask Google to remove any email from me I have send, not only from my account (you can do it yourself easily, BTW) but also from the account of the people who have received the mail (provided it is still there and owned by Google) and the Google server. I do not see why that's would not be possible. At the other hand, at least in some countries (Belgium, for example) email is the legal equivalent of a paper letter and can be used to prove something (that you have agreed to a contract, for example). This would obviously jeopardize this. Note that a paper letter would not be necessarily better... Has someone an experience about how the GDPR is interpreted?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Law.SE. It would help if you could as a more specific question. For instance, do you want to know about how email you have sent to other people is treated by the GDPR?

Comment: @Paul Johnson. Yes, in particular, what right, if any, do the sender have on the emails on the recipient account. I assume it is a real email really send by the sender, I do not speak of forged emails send by hackers.

Comment: I don't agree that you can ask Google to remove your emails from the accounts that have received that email. See the related question [Private Messages I sent to others will never be deleted/erased from Facebook servers](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/30951/18215).

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that?

Comment: @Paul Johnson. I agree it is a duplicate. But there were apparently no legal precedent. Unless things have changed since it was answered, I would consider that this answers my question.