# Is WhatsApp GDPR compliant as it allows backups for group chat?

Tags: software, gdpr

Currently WhatsApp claims it uses end to end encryption.

However the app provisions users to switch on backups to Google Drive and other providers. So if I am in a group chat with a set of users and send out sensitive/personal information, I assume I can delete my chat at any time and make a request to WhatsApp to delete any information on me when I delete my account.

However if other users are backing up their chats to say Google Drive etc how can I ensure my data is deleted from everywhere?

I understand anyone can just screenshot or copy this data from their device and paste it somewhere. But the app itself provisions for these backups so does WhatsApp have a duty under Right to Erasure / GDPR to ensure they can also be deleted if a request is made for an individual?

Comment: WhatsApp doesn’t even have a duty to delete the messages from other members devices, let alone backups, because this is no longer just *your* information. This is another variation on https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/30951/facebook-vs-gdpr-private-messages-i-sent-to-others-will-never-be-deleted-erase

Comment: Thanks this looks the same question then. Thats really annoying, I can understand its on someone elses device but their software is provisioning further transfer to other data sources. Annoying!